# authlogic and ajax in place editing with rails, also routing issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, authentication, edit-in-place

I'm trying to use Authlogic to protect some in place editor fields I have on a page. I've protected all the methods in my controller, but it looks like in_place_editor is calling some weird generated stuff that doesn't even show up in my routes, like "/quotes/set_quote_text/1". Number one is there a site that tells more about these "secret" routes? Or is this something that in place edit added that I don't know about? It's just kind of unnerving that it doesn't even show up when I display all routes.

Assuming I do find out this, I have no idea how to protect things that aren't methods in my controller. Can I protect a whole route?

Another question is that, even if I do restrict the update route, the in place editor fields are rendering for everything. I would imagine that the way to do this would be to create a helper which would render the appropriate version depending on if the user is logged in or not. I am just not sure what I'd be checking against to see if someone's logged in or not, since I've been doing it all in the controller...Also, tips for that: would the partial just render one of 2 versions of a partial depending on the logged in state, or is there another way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

By default Rails includes the following routes:

```
map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
```

Furthermore, as you probably know, all public controller methods serve as controller actions.

Consider the following controller:

```
class SampleController < ActionController::Base
  def test
    render :text => "text"
  end
end
```

So with the default routes, `/sample/test` will call `SampleController#test`

Also worth knowing is that `in_place_edit_for(object, attribute, options = {})` defines a new method on the controller called `set_#{object}_#{attribute}`. In your case, this is `set_quote_text`.

To answer your questions:

- **Why doesn't the route show up in `rake routes`**:
  Almost certainly this is because it's using that default route that I talked about at the beginning. I often times remove these routes so that only routes I explicitly define will be used.
- **How can one protect the in_place_edit action?**:
  Now that you know the name of the action you can add it to your list of protected actions. I assume you have something along the lines of `before_filter :authentication_required, :only => LIST_OF_ACTIONS_REQUIRING_AUTHENTICATION`. Safer than this however is to use except and provide a list of all actions that you do not want to protect: `before_filter :authentication_required, :except => LIST_OF_ACTIONS_THAT_DON'T_REQUIRE_AUTHENTICATION`

Hopefully that's what you need.

Comment: Thanks, the :except method is way safer and covers more cases. However I guess I'm still confused about the fact that it makes several routes. If I did want to protect those in particular, how could I feasibly because there are so many routes generated for each attribute? Could I protect all of the set_ routes overall?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. There's only one route generated per attribute, unless you're referring to something else.